# Checking network responses from a URL for a JSON using python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, web-scraping

I need to get the JSON containing the info from this URL hkex.com.hk, I can do so using firefox>developer tools>network  and looking for the JSON I want, I need to do the same using python, so far I have this

```py
url='https://www.hkex.com.hk/Market-Data/Securities-Prices/Equities?sc_lang=en'
r = requests.get(url)
print(r.text)
```

But I only receive an HTML so even after using .json() I get an error "Expecting value" because it is empty, how can I achieve this?

Comment: Which part of the page are you trying to extract?

Comment: the info from the table "https://www.hkex.com.hk/Market-Data/Securities-Prices/Equities?sc_lang=en"                                            I can find it in network>other there are 3 .JSON I need the last one, this one: https://www1.hkex.com.hk/hkexwidget/data/getequityfilter?lang=eng&token=evLtsLsBNAUVTPxtGqVeG8QpVRBPNt2I8CbDELLpyZv%2bff8QFzdfZ6w1Za4TWSJ6&sort=5&order=0&qid=1627367921383&callback=jQuery35106295196366220494_1627367912871&_=1627367912873

Comment: Ah, if you can't find a network call, your best bet is to use something like BeautifulSoup (https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to scrape the page and extract the table's information from html.

Comment: the problem is that the HTML has no data, the data is located in the .JSON which is what I'm trying to access

Comment: The HTML of the page (https://www.hkex.com.hk/Market-Data/Securities-Prices/Equities?sc_lang=en) does seem to have the data in the `table->tr->td` tags.

Comment: Yeah, the data is in the .JSON that I'm trying to get, the problem is that I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Ignore the JSON. Scrape the data from the HTML using BeatifulSoup.

Comment: @PriyanshAgrawal I already tried, but the HTML has none of the info included in the JSON

Answer (score 0):

The response request is an html text, so you are not able to use json() method on the entire response.
There should be another way to "convert" html into json, but you will have to find the part of html you want to convert to.

Comment: None of the HTML is part of my JSON, the HTML is just the HTML of the website, the JSON is received as a separate file .JSON, I can find it in firefox>network>others but I don't know how to access that using python

Answer (score 0):

The json is indeed hidden in the url you mention in one of your comments. You have to get the html, extract the json and load it:

```
url = 'https://www1.hkex.com.hk/hkexwidget/data/getequityfilter?lang=eng&token=evLtsLsBNAUVTPxtGqVeG8QpVRBPNt2I8CbDELLpyZv%2bff8QFzdfZ6w1Za4TWSJ6&sort=5&order=0&qid=1627367921383&callback=jQuery35106295196366220494_1627367912871&_=1627367912873'
req = requests.get(url)
#now for the extraction:
target = req.text.split('jQuery35106295196366220494_1627367912871(')[1].split(')')[0]
#EDIT
target = req.text.split('(')[1].split(')')[0]
data = json.loads(target)
data
```

The output should be your json.

Comment: The problem is that the URL with the jQuery351..... changes every day, so I can't use the same, to get the updated URL with the .JSON I need to load this "https://www.hkex.com.hk/Market-Data/Securities-Prices/Equities?sc_lang=en" and using the developer tools of firefox find the new link of the new .JSON, that part is what I whish to automate using python

Comment: @FddeF Sorry; you didn't mention it in the question so I didn't know. One possible way around that is to drop the refrence to the JQ.. string and just split on `(`, as in `.split('(')`. It should generally work.

Comment: I'm sorry, you seem well known on the topic, could you elaborate a bit more on what are we trying to do to JQ... using `.split('(')`  ?